# How do you make the CSS shadow look the same in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, shadow

Here is my link: [link text](http://www.logicpkg.com/index.htm)

The shadow on the slider looks great in safari, firefox, etc., but how do I make it look the same in IE?

Here is my current CSS code:

```
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #666;          
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #666;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #666;
```

Comment: @eric, use background shadwow images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it works in IE 6+ too

```
.shadow { zoom:1; /* This enables hasLayout, which is required for older IE browsers */        
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#b0b0b0', Direction=135, Strength=3);        
-moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 2px #b0b0b0;        
-webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 2px #b0b0b0;
box-shadow:2px 2px 2px #b0b0b0;}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/), it adds a bunch of CSS3-isms to IE. CSS3PIE usually works but not always and there is a bit of a performance hit. You might have to deal with "haslayout" hacks but a bit of googling should help with those.

There are a few similar things kicking around but I've only used CSS3PIE.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is better you use shadow images so that it works fine in IE too....